# drilling through the DOM with jquery

Tags: jquery, dom

If I'm trying to put text in one of the the vote-tally elements below, how would I refer to it in jquery?

```
<ul class="round round-1">
        <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>

        <li class="game game-top pair1">
            <span class="left-rail">
                <span class="seed">1</span>
                <span class="vote-tally"></span>
            </span>
            <span class="right-rail">
                <span class="lead-img"><img src="img/myimage.jpg"></span>
                <span class="name-text">First guy</span>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li class="game game-bottom pair1">
        <span class="left-rail">
            <span class="seed">16</span>
            <span class="vote-tally"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="right-rail">
            <span class="lead-img"><img src="img/anotherimg.jpg"></span>
            <span class="name-text">Second guy</span>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jquery:

```
$('.round-1').find('.game-top .pair1').find('.left-rail').find('.vote-tally').text('5'); //doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre selector at this level should be chaind:

```
 .find('.game-top.pair1')
```

or like this:

```
$('.round-1').find('.game-top.pair1 .left-rail .vote-tally').text('5');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use child selectors in jQuery like this:

```
    var elem = $(".round-1 > .game-top.pair1 > .left-rail > .vote-tally");
    elem.text("5");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wahwahwah/981jm8v1/15/)